# Prove that a local-minimum spanning tree is also a minimum spanning tree.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

$G$ is a weighted connected graph. Let $T(G)$ be the graph that has the spanning trees of $G$ as vertices, and two spanning trees are adjacent to each other if and only if each one of them has only one edge that the other doesn't have. To each vertex of $T(G)$ we associate the weight of the spanning tree that corresponds to it.

Let $T_1$ be any vertex of $T(G)$, that is, any spanning tree of $G$. Prove that $T_1$ is a local minimum if and only if $T_1$ is a global minimum.

To put it in another words, prove that $T_1$ has weight less than or equal to all its neighbours in $T(G)$ if and only if $T_1$ is a minimum spanning tree.

Answer (score 5):

Let $T$ be a local minimum spanning tree that is not a global minimum.
Let $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ the edges of $T$ ordered by non-decreasing weight.
Let $T'$ be a minimum weight spanning tree that coincides with $T$ on the largest possible begin segment,
so we may assume $T'$ has edges $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1},f_n,\ldots,f_m$ (again ordered by non-decreasing weight)
and $f_n\ne e_n$. Let $w$ be the weight function in our graph.

We claim that $w(f_n)<w(e_n)$: indeed, if $w(e_n)\leq w(f_n)$ then $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1},e_n$ would
be a valid startup for Kruskal's algorithm and would lead to a minimum weight spanning tree that
coincides with $T$ on a larger initial segment.

$T+f_n$ contains exactly one cycle $C$. The edges of $C$ different from $f_n$ cannot all be in
$\{e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$ or we would have a cycle in $T'$. So we find at least one edge $f$ on $C$ that
is different from $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}$ and $f_n$. But then $w(f)\geq w(e_n)>w(f_n)$,
so $T+f_n-f$ is a spanning tree with a smaller total weight that is a neighbour of $T$ in the spanning tree graph. Contradiction.

(I left some small details for you to prove. Let me know if they cause trouble).

Note that this proves the slightly stronger statement, that each non-minimal tree has
a neighbour of strictly smaller total weight.

Comment: It looks like this approach assumes that Kruskal's algorithm can find every minimum spanning tree, a fact that might not be trivial to prove.

Comment: I fail to see where that assumption is used in the proof. Can you elaborate?

Comment: "$e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1},e_n$ would be a valid startup for Kruskal's algorithm". Why is "$e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}"$ a valid startup for Kruskal's algorithm? You have assumed that fact, which may not be trivial to prove.

Comment: There are three ways to remedy the situation. One way is to consider Kruskal's algorithm can find every minimum spanning tree as a known fact. A second way is to prove that fact right here. The third way is, instead of "let $T'$ be a minimum weight spanning tree that coincides with $T$ on the largest possible begin segment", we can "let $T'$ be a minimum weight spanning tree obtainable by Kruskal's algorithm that coincides with $T$ on the largest possible begin segment".

Comment: The reason that $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}$ is a valid startup follows from the assumption in the first paragraph that $e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1},f_n,\ldots,f_m$ is ordered by non-decreasing weight.

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in my answer to the question [are all MST minimum spanning trees reachable by Kruskal and Prim?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95625/917535).

Comment: By the way, I had upvoted this answer when I wrote my first comment. Once you have updated your answer, we can remove all comments here.

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm is not deterministic, it makes choices. Therefore every nondecreasing sequence is a possible outcome. Every startsegment of a nondecreasing sequence is a possible startsequence.

Comment: "It makes choices." Why do the choices it makes will not miss any MST? Suppose you find an MST by Prim's algorithm. Why does that MST can be found by Kruskal? If I say that for any problem, a correct algorithm that finds one solution will be able to find all solutions if it makes choices, you can surely give a counterexample. Then why does the choices made by Kruskal for MST cover all possibilities? Have you read [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95625/917535)?

Comment: I feel that I have exhausted my possibilities to explain this to you.
I suggest you open a question of your own, asking why every edge-list with non-decreasing edge-weights is a possible outcome of Kruskal's algorithm. Maybe there is someone out there who can explain it better.

Comment: "Every edge-list with non-decreasing edge-weights is a possible outcome of Kruskal's algorithm" is obviously false. For example, a triangle of weight 1, 2, 3. The edge-list of the single edge of weight 2 is not a possibility. The edge-list of the edge of weight 2 and the edge of weight 3 is not a possibility, either.

Comment: Every edge-list *containing all edges* with ....

Comment: "Every edge-list containing all edges with non-decreasing edge-weights is a possible outcome of Kruskal's algorithm." This does not make much sense. For example, a triangle of weight 1, 2, 3. What is an edge-list containing all edges with ...?

Comment: Seriously? What do you think the edge-list with non-decreasing edge-weights could be if the edge weights are $1,2,3$? This has been my last reply. Seek help elsewhere, hate me, whatever you like.

Comment: Do you mean the edge list is the list of the edge of weight 1, the edge of weight 2, the edge of weight 3? That list is not an *outcome* of Kruskal's algorithm. (Do you mean input to Kruskal?)

Comment: OK, please seek help elsewhere, hate me, whatever you like. This has been my last reply.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure if this proof is correct, so feel free to discuss and point out the errors. My intention was to arrive at a proof without the consideration of greedy algorithms such as Kruskal's. This is because the claim that "every local optimum is a global optimum (which is to be proved) forms the basis of such algorithms.*

Suppose not that is, there exists a local minimal spanning tree $T=(e_1,e_2,...e_m)$ which differs from the (global) minimal spanning tree, say $T'=(e_1,e_2,...e_{n-1},f_n,...f_m), \sum_{j=n}^m w(f_j)\ne \sum_{j=n}^m w(e_j)$. [This last assumption is required so as to truly say that $T$ is **not** the global spanning tree.]

Now, we define the neighbourhood of a spanning tree, $t$ as $N(t)=\{s: s\text{ is a spanning tree obtained as: add an edge to }t\text{, delete an edge from the cycle formed}\}.$
Hence, there exist spanning trees $S_n,S_{n+1},...S_m\in N(T)$ such that
$$S_n=(e_1,e_2,...e_{n-1},f_n,e_{n+1},...e_m),\quad S_{n+1}=(e_1,e_2,...e_n,f_{n+1},e_{n+2},...e_m)\quad...$$
Since, $T$ is a local optimum it has less weight than each of its neighbours. So, we can write
$$w(f_n)\ge w(e_n),\quad w(f_{n+1})\ge w(e_{n+1}),\quad...$$
Summing these up we get, $$\sum_{i=1}^m w(e_i)\le\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}w(e_i)+\sum_{j=n}^m w(f_j)\Rightarrow\text{weight of }T\le\text{weight of }T'.$$
But, $T'$ is the minimal spanning tree and $\sum_{j=n}^m w(f_j)\ne \sum_{j=n}^m w(e_j)\Rightarrow$ weight of $T'<$ weight of $T$. We arrive at a contradiction. Hence, a local MST is necessarily a global MST.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk do you mind giving some input on the proof? I'm not confident about it and I believe you know more about the topic.